# How do I solve the problem of summarizing the score?

Tags: r

I put like below!

```
text_sentiments <- text_words %>%
  inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn"), by = "word") %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(value = sum(score * n) / sum(n))
```

and my data for 'text_words' is:

```
> text_words
# A tibble: 523 x 3
   year  id          word     
 <chr> <chr>       <chr>    
 1 2012  a120225.txt limit    
 2 2012  a120225.txt striking 
 3 2012  a120225.txt intensity
 4 2012  a120225.txt range    
 5 2012  a120225.txt army     
 6 2012  a120225.txt people   
 7 2012  a120225.txt spokesman
 8 2012  a120225.txt dprk     
 9 2012  a120225.txt national 
10 2012  a120225.txt defence  
# … with 513 more rows
>
```

And the error i'm getting is:
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `score`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
ℹ Input `score` is `sum(score * n)/sum(n)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: year = "2012".

Thank you so much for you care!

Comment: can you please add your input data? You can use `dput()` to paste into your question.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I'm going to hazard a wild guess and say that `score` [or `n`], for some reason, is a character.  But I can't be sure because you haven't shown us your data.  (Have you looked at your data yourself?)  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: I corrected my question!

Comment: There is no `score` or `n` column in your data. `get_sentiments` function return only 2 columns i.e `word` and `value`.